# update postgres table columns form another table if column is empty and within 2 hrs of timeframe

Tags: database, postgresql

I have two tables below with sample data.

Table_1:

```
| bid|first_nid|  first_datetime     |second_nid|  second_datetime    |third_nid|   third_datetime    |
|:--:|:-------:|:-------------------:|:--------:|:-------------------:|:-------:|:-------------------:|
| 06 |   6022  | 2023-04-10 14:51:53 |          |                     |         |                     |
| 20 |   6022  | 2023-04-10 14:13:18 |   6005   | 2023-04-10 14:14:24 |  6004   | 2023-04-10 14:14:59 |
| 27 |   6022  | 2023-04-15 09:29:00 |   6005   | 2023-04-15 09:30:28 |         |                     |
| 17 |   6022  | 2023-04-15 08:29:00 |          |                     |         |                     |
```

Table_2:

```
| bid|second_nid|   second_datetime   |third_nid|   third_datetime    |
|:--:|:--------:|:-------------------:|:-------:|:-------------------:|
| 06 |   6005   | 2023-04-10 14:52:24 |         |                     |
| 06 |   6005   | 2023-04-10 17:52:24 |         |                     |
| 27 |   6005   | 2023-04-15 09:35:01 |  6004   | 2023-04-15 09:41:13 |
| 17 |   6005   | 2023-04-15 08:45:01 |  6004   | 2023-04-15 09:10:13 |
| 17 |   6005   | 2023-04-15 11:45:01 |  6004   | 2023-04-15 11:10:13 |
```

Note - second_nid,second_datetime is one set and third_nid,third_datetime is one set, means either both nid and datetime column will have values or both will be empty in both the tables.

I am trying to update Table_1 only 4 columns(second_nid,second_datetime,third_nid,third_datetime) from Table_2 based on '**bid**' if -
Condition 1 - update second_nid,second_datetime, third_nid,third_datetime if empty in Table_1 AND second_datetime,third_datetime is within 2 hrs of first_datetime(e.g.- bid=17)
Condition 2 - update only third_nid,third_datetime if second_nid,second_datetime already have values and third_datetime is within 2 hrs of first_datetime in Table_1.(e.g.- bid=06)

Update Table_1:

```
| bid|first_nid|    first_datetime   |second_nid|   second_datetime   |third_nid|    third_datetime   |
|:--:|:-------:|:-------------------:|:--------:|:-------------------:|:-------:|:-------------------:|
| 06 |   6022  | 2023-04-10 14:51:53 |   6005   | 2023-04-10 14:52:24 |         |                     |
| 20 |   6022  | 2023-04-10 14:13:18 |   6005   | 2023-04-10 14:14:24 |   6004  | 2023-04-10 14:14:59 |
| 27 |   6022  | 2023-04-15 09:29:00 |   6005   | 2023-04-15 09:30:28 |   6004  | 2023-04-15 09:41:13 |
| 17 |   6022  | 2023-04-15 08:29:00 |   6005   | 2023-04-15 08:45:01 |   6004  | 2023-04-15 09:10:13 |
```

Setup table queries:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
bid character varying(2) NOT NULL,
first_nid character varying(5) NOT NULL,
first_datetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
second_nid character varying(5),
second_datetime timestamp without time zone,
third_nid character varying(5),
third_datetime timestamp without time zone, PRIMARY KEY(bid, first_nid, first_datetime));

INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES
      (06, '6022', '2023-04-10 14:51:53', '', NULL, '', NULL)
    , (20, '6022', '2023-04-10 14:13:18', '6005', '2023-04-10 14:14:24', '6004', '2023-04-10 14:14:59')
    , (27, '6022', '2023-04-15 09:29:00', '6005', '2023-04-15 09:30:28', '', NULL)
    , (17, '6022', '2023-04-15 08:29:00', '', NULL, '', NULL)
    ;
    
CREATE TABLE table_2 (
bid character varying(2) NOT NULL,
second_nid character varying(5) NOT NULL,
second_datetime timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
third_nid character varying(5),
third_datetime timestamp without time zone,
PRIMARY KEY(bid, second_nid, second_datetime)
);

INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES
      (06, '6005', '2023-04-10 14:52:24', '', NULL)
    , (06, '6005', '2023-04-10 17:52:24', '', NULL)
    , (27, '6005', '2023-04-15 09:35:01', '6004', '2023-04-15 09:41:13')
    , (17, '6005', '2023-04-15 08:45:01', '6004', '2023-04-15 09:10:13')
    , (17, '6005', '2023-04-15 11:45:01', '6004', '2023-04-15 11:10:13')
    ;
```

Test Env -
https://dbfiddle.uk/Fr7p-Pdd

Comment: The term _empty_ is ambiguous. From the setup script it appears that _empty_ means either `NULL` or a zero-length string. A zero-length string is not the same as _unvalued_. Consider following the convention that _unvalued_ is always represented by `NULL` instead of a special value.

Comment: @JohnH..this is how I am receiving the data. Looking for the solution with same data. Sorry I can't change that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original question specified "within 2 hours" but didn't define what that means. The following code assumes that the intent was for the comparison time to be at or after *t1.first_datetime* and at or before *t1.first_datetime + 2 hours*. Modifying the time comparisons for other interpretations is a trivial exercise.

```
UPDATE table_1 t1
  SET second_nid = COALESCE(NULLIF(t1.second_nid, ''), t2.second_nid),
      second_datetime = COALESCE(t1.second_datetime, t2.second_datetime),
      third_nid = COALESCE(NULLIF(t1.third_nid, ''), t2.third_nid),
      third_datetime = COALESCE(t1.third_datetime, t2.third_datetime)
FROM
  table_2 t2
WHERE t1.bid = t2.bid
  AND ((    coalesce(t1.second_datetime, t1.third_datetime) IS NULL
        AND t2.second_datetime BETWEEN t1.first_datetime AND t1.first_datetime + interval '2' hour)
       OR (    t1.second_datetime IS NOT NULL
           AND t1.third_datetime IS NULL
           AND t2.third_datetime BETWEEN t1.first_datetime AND t1.first_datetime + interval '2' hour));
```

If more than one row satisfies these conditions for the same *bid*, then the row used to perform the update is indeterminate.

Comment: @RKIDEV If the above resolved your issue then please accept the answer. This may help future questioners with same/similar question and it removes the question form the unanswered queue. Please do not leave successfully answered questions as unanswered.